# How can I install Java JDK on an External Hard Drive?

Tags: java, linux, ant, ubuntu

I am running Lubuntu LXDE on an Acer C720 Chromebook and don't have a lot of space. I need to run Android SDK, but it takes up a lot of space. For right now I would also like to install JDK on the External Hard Drive as well; however, I can't seem to get it right. I unpacked the .tar.gz file into a directory in the External Hard Drive and set the path to it but if I go into lxterminal to see the version it looks like this:

> (Android_Dev)taserman21@localhost:/$ java -version 
>   bash: /media/removable/USB Drive/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java: Permission denied

I have tried changing the permissions of the whole External Hard Drive, the directory, and the java file itself but nothing seems to be working.

I also installed Ant manually and tried to run that too but this happens:

> (Android_Dev)taserman21@localhost:~$ ant -version 
>   Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. 
>   We cannot execute /media/removable/USB Drive/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java

Please help, as I have not found a tutorial for this or even whether or not this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from the fact that **[Ubuntu refuse to execute files from an NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30243/why-does-ubuntu-refuse-to-execute-files-from-an-ntfs-partition)** by default settings. (Lubuntu is a vairiant of Ubuntu)

If you remount the external hard drive **without `noexec` and `users` option** (requires root), or if you have `EXT3` formatted external hard drive (requires time and/or money :-) ), it would work fine. See an example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/#11843) to change mount options. It is also possible to [change this mount options with the graphical user interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99477/running-executables-on-an-ntfs-partition).

You should know that [NTFS is actually *IS* POSIX compliant](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976809.aspx) and supports permissions, if mounted appropriately. Please [see this Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223016/setting-permission-for-ntfs-partition).

If you want to know more, you shoud read [man page of `ntfs-3g`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g) by issuing command:

```
man ntfs-3g
```

It seems that you know about `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and have set it correctly, because otherwise shell could not be able to find it, as it could in your output.

Comment: I can't seem to find the noexec or users option in the mount options. Is there a different problem here? I have been trying your way for about an hour now.

Answer (score 0):

As Ho1 said, you can't execute something in a ntfs partition, **by default**

A method to execute files on ntfs partition is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223016/setting-permission-for-ntfs-partition)

Answer (score 0):

First issue is if you are trying to execute something from an NTFS partition, which Ubuntu does not allow by default. Edit the file `/etc/fstab` and remove the `noexec` command from the mapping.

Second issue may be with how your environment is set up. Is there an environment property setup in your console? Easiest way to find out is to run `set` from the command line.it will display all of the properties for that console. If you don't see `JAVA_HOME`, then you need to `set` and `export` it.

`set JAVA_HOME=/PATH/TO/YOUR/JDK`

`export JAVA_HOME`